# play audio only when button is pressed otherwise not in android

Tags: android

I want to make an entertainment app which will produce sound only when the play button is pressed, but it is not working properly .

My code is

```
final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();       
play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        try{  
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("3dpolicesi_mAYkXAbm.mp3");
                long start = descriptor.getStartOffset();
                long end = descriptor.getLength();

                mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();

                mp.stop();

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();} 
    }
} );
```

Comment: In your code, you're starting the MediaPlayer and calling mp.stop() immediately.. that will stop the sound so it will never be played

Answer (score 0):

It is because mp.stop() is called directly after mp.start(). It won't get a chance to play.

Answer (score 0):

First delete this 3 line of your code:

```
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
mp.stop();
```

Write this outside of onClick:

```
int x = 0;
```

Then write this inside of onClick:

```
if(x == 0){
  mp.start();
  x = 1;
}else if(x == 1){
  mp.stop();
  x = 0;
}
```

At first time x is 0 so when you click on button player will be start and x will be replace with 1. next time when you click on button x is 1 so player will be stop.I hope it help.